# Conditional execution of the plot command

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot to create graphs of a rather simply structured file. In particular, the file contains 8 columns, the first 4 columns describe "measured" values, the second 4 "predicted" values. I want to create two plots, one comprising only measured values, one comprising both.

Since my gnuplot script is rather long, I would like to introduce a variable to set the flag whether predicted values should be contained or not. I want to use different line types, axis and labels, and hence, cannot use the "[using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178928/how-to-use-gnuplot-to-do-conditional-plot)" approach.

Here is what I use so far:

```
plot 'file.txt' using 2:xticlabels(1) title "Val1 (Measured)" with
lines axes x1y1, '' using 3:xticlabels(1) title "Val2 (Measured)"
with linespoints axes x1y2;

if (settingCompareToAggretagion == 1)
   plot 'file.txt' using 4:xticlabels(1) title "Val1 (Aggregated)" with lines
   axes x1y1, '' using 5:xticlabels(1) title "Val2" with linespoints axes x1y2;
```

There is obviously the problem that I get two plots but one. I also tried to "attach" the second set of plots to the command with an inline if condition (`bool.exrp. ? x : y`) but this is not working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with the `replot` command:

```
plot x, x**2
replot x+5, x**2 + 5
```

That plots a single graph with four plots.

In your case the following should work:

```
plot 'file.txt' u 2:xtic(1) t "Val1 (Measured)" w l,\
     '' u 3 t "Val2 (Measured)" w lp axes x1y2

if (settingCompareToAggregation == 1) {
    replot 'file.txt' u 4 t "Val1 (Aggregated)" w l,\
           '' u 5 t "Val2 (Aggregated)" w lp axes x1y2
}
```